# Notifcation area icons - cleanup icons from killed processes

Tags: windows, winapi

Notification-area icons for killed processes will disappear if you mouseover them, as this makes Windows check whether the associated process is still running.

Is there a way to trigger this cleanup process programatically?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to trigger this cleanup process programatically?

No there is not. I've seen some programs use `SendInput` to put the cursor over the notification area, but that feels rather dirty to me.